# jquery ajax setup with authorization headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using these code to set authorization headers with ajax setup but its not working

```
 $.ajaxSetup({

   beforeSend: function(xhr, options) {

    var encoded_auth_token, header;
    if (Remon.Auth.get('auth_token')) {
        console.log("there is a request");//triggered 
        encoded_auth_token = Base64.encode64(Remon.Auth.get('auth_token') + ":X");
        header = "Basic " + encoded_auth_token;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", header);
        return true;

      }
    },
error: function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 401) {

        console.log("unauth");
    }
    if (xhr.status === 404) {
         console.log("wrong");
    }
  }
});
```

no request headers are set I have Base64 included also Remon.get("auth_token") working and console.log is triggered

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors popping up in console? Your 'there is a request' log is showing: see if logging the `auth_token` and `encoded_auth_token` yields sensible results

Comment: the problem is the auth_token not send ,when I do normal ajax request $.ajax{data:token}, its working but ajaxsetup not working

Comment: The basics of your `$.ajaxSetup` are correct: and if I remove/substitute the `Remon.Auth` and `Base64` lines in your code it works: [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br36c/) with the commented-out sections. The network console does show the Authorization header being sent: therefore, the problem likely exists somewhere in the `Remon` or `Base64` objects and their methods - something is causing an error between your `console.log` call and `xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", header );`

Comment: It's not a CORS request, is it?

Comment: I setup my cors and my rails application is working well with ajax requests but ajaxsetup not working